# yum package trying to get update from disabled repo

Tags: yum

```
[****-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius]
bandwidth = 0
base_persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server
baseurl = https://ordproxy.rhn.****.com/XMLRPC/GET-REQ/****-rhel-
x86_64-server-6-ius
cache = 0
cachedir = /var/cache/yum/*****-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius
cost = 1000
enabled = 0
```

The ius repo is disabled already. But while giving yum update the following package showsup.

```
@server]#yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package redis32u.x86_64 0:3.2.10-2.ius.el6 will be updated
---> Package redis32u.x86_64 0:3.2.11-1.ius.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                              Arch                               Version                                      Repository                                                      Size
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 redis32u                             x86_64                             3.2.11-1.ius.el6                             *****-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius                             515 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 515 k
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Comment: Have you tried to run 'yum clean all' first?

Comment: Tried yum clean all ... yum clean all metada

Comment: Is it possible you have the repo defined twice. Search for it in yum repo files in /etc/yum. repos.d/*

Comment: yum repolist disabled | grep ius
ius-archive                   IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x8
ius-archive-debuginfo         IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x8
ius-archive-source            IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x8
ius-dev                       IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x8

Comment: # yum repolist enabled | grep ius
*****-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius    ****** - RHEL (v. 6 for 64-bit x 10,054

Comment: Disabled the repo in rhnplugin.conf

Answer (score 1):

`[****-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius]` looks an awful lot like a channel name in Satellite.  If that is the case, disabling the repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/ius.repo` won't help you.  In fact, if you are using IUS as a Satellite channel then you should remove ius-release and any manually created IUS repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` to avoid exactly this confusion.  You should ask your Satellite admin (hosting provider?) to disable the channel for you, or you can disable it locally (or just exclude certain packages) by adding appropriate yum directives to `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf`.